# hdf5 warning with simple key check in h5py

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

When I open an h5 file `file.h5` with h5py and check for a certain key:
then this does not work:

```
found = "data" in h5File.keys() # warning on this line
if found:
         a = h5File["data"][...]
```

and spits out the following warning:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.15-patch1) thread 0:
   #000: /cluster/home/nuetzig/installHDF5/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/src/H5Gdeprec.c line 893 in H5Gget_objinfo(): not a location
     major: Invalid arguments to routine
     minor: Inappropriate type
   #001: /cluster/home/nuetzig/installHDF5/hdf5-1.8.15-patch1/src/H5Gloc.c line 173 in H5G_loc(): invalid file ID
     major: Invalid arguments to routine
     minor: Bad value
```

However making a set from `h5File.keys()` which is of type `KeysViewWithLock(<HDF5 file "file.h5" (mode r)>)` 
works:

```
found = "data" in set(h5File.keys()) 
if found:
    a = h5File["data"][...]
```

Anybody some idea where the problem is?

I have to say, that the file resides on a parallel network storage (Lustre) on a cluster...
Note: also `"data" in h5File` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

Reinstalled h5py manually 
by

```
python3 setup.py configure --hdf5-version=1.8.15
python3 install
```

Somehow the version did not get set and it used 1.8.4, dont know why...